# Windows 7 explorer locking file and crash

Tags: windows-7, crash

It happens quite often that when attempting to copy files between folders, Windows 7 will crash, restart, and all my open explorer will be gone. Most of time it's due to copying locked file. Is there any way to let Windows 7 not crash all the time by disable something ?

**EDIT: (request to reopen the thread)**

How to reproduce: say folder "project1' is a Visual Studio 2010 folder, which contains the whole solution. After done with updating the project, I close the solution, but not Visual Studio. Also close TortoiseHg client after commit the last change. So these 2 applications are not likely to lock any folder/file. 
Also, I've closed all related files in editor, so editor application won't lock any file.

Then I tried to copy the 'porject1' folder to another place (in different drive). This action causes my explorer crash, generating report, and close all explorer instances. The 'project1' folder didn't get copied to destination.

This is log from Reliability Monitor.

```
Windows Explorer
Problem: stopped working
Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: BEX64
Application Name:   Explorer.EXE
Application Version:    6.1.7601.17514
Application Timestamp:  4ce7a144
Fault Module Name:  MSVCR80.dll
Fault Module Version:   8.0.50727.4940
Fault Module Timestamp: 4ca2b4dd
Exception Offset:   000000000001df0d
Exception Code: c000000d
Exception Data: 0000000000000000
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   5e1d
Additional Information 2:   5e1d64e35e71b3f9a1bf3e209e6282fe
Additional Information 3:   92cc
Additional Information 4:   92cc0a832a0ad8ac8f072256bf80ab54

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  1648840625
```

This restart is really annoying. How can I further troubleshooting this issue? In Windows XP, if file gets locked, explorer will just pop up an error message. Is there any way to set Win 7 to do the same?

Comment: Does this happen in safe mode as well?

Comment: Can you establish any kind of pattern for this error? This is not a known error and not something commonly experienced thus I doubt a "silver bullet" fix will be available. As it stands I'm voting to close as well unless more details are added.

Comment: If he recently put a power hungry new graphics card in but didn't upgrade the PSU it could be causing a lag in his hdd.  But without info who knows?

Answer (score 2):

I'd check the logs. Windows 7 has a great Reliability Monitor (search it under start menu) that will show you every error and warning. Hopefully it should shed some light on what's causing the crashes.

If that doesn't work. http://www.sandboxie.com will allow you to sandbox various parts of Windows which may be causing Explorer to crash.